# Text AND background-image on input[type='submit']

Tags: html, forms, css

`<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Search" class="button search">`

Is it possible to apply a CSS gradient using `background-image:` and still show the text contained in the `value` attribute?

When I add a background-image it hides the text.

Any help much appreciated

**EDIT**

Here are the computed styles to match the markup

```
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -webkit-background-clip: border-box;
    -webkit-background-origin: padding-box;
    -webkit-background-size: auto;
    -webkit-border-image: none;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.701961) 0px 0px 6px 0px inset, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392) 0px 2px 3px 0px;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.30000001192092896s;
    -webkit-transition-property: all;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-user-select: text;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-clip: border-box;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FF8F25 0%, #FF6D00 100%);
    background-origin: padding-box;
    background-position: 0% 0%;
    background-size: auto;
    border-bottom-color: #BE4B00;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-left-color: #BE4B00;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-right-color: #BE4B00;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-right-width: 1px;
    border-top-color: #BE4B00;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    bottom: 10px;
    box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.701961) 0px 0px 6px 0px inset, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392) 0px 2px 3px 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    font-family: 'Lucida Grande';
    font-size: 12px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: 800;
    height: 26px;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    line-height: 26px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    max-height: 24px;
    outline-color: white;
    outline-style: none;
    outline-width: 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-top: 24px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 8px;
    text-align: center;
    text-indent: 0px;
    text-shadow: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    white-space: pre;
    width: 85px;
    word-spacing: 0px
```

**SOLVED**

Was a padding issue pushing the text down. Seems like in Chrome on the Mac padding can be applied without affecting the height so that the text is pushed down out of view.

Thanks for the help guys

Comment: Y do u need background-image: and y not background-color??

Comment: did u check the answer below? is that what u  need?

Comment: @SowmyaShivaram yeah didn't help unfortunately I'll post the CSS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS

```
input {
background-color: #D28888;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#690707), to(#D28888));
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #690707 0%, #D28888 100%);
    border:none; padding:6px 12px; color:#fff; cursor:pointer
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZSrHh/2/)**
​

---

By using `background-image`

```
input {
background-image: url(http://alanbooth.net/alap/images/gradient.bmp);
border:none;
padding:6px 12px;
color:#fff;
cursor:pointer
}
​
```

**[DEMO - 2](http://jsfiddle.net/ZSrHh/3/)**

Comment: Thanks for the effort and the demos but unfortunately it didn't solve the problem. I've posted the CSS above, any ideas?

Comment: @JackMahoney y do you need that many properties for simple button? you can write the border radius in one line, u have used more than 8 lines for that. Check this demo http://jsfiddle.net/ZSrHh/6/

Comment: @SowmyaShivaram - they are the computed styles from Chrome. Worked it out - padding issue! Thanks for you help